# svg.path issues with parse_pathif

Tags: python, svg

I'm using svg.path for graph analysis
I'm trying to find out the bigger curve but I don't understand meaning of control1 control2 and why their is an factor 'j'
if someone already worked on svg files and can help me thank you that will be great (thank you my g)
my  code :

````
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath, options=chromeOptions) 
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YykAzF8MqA4&ab_channel=LORISGIULIANO')
sleep(5)

btm = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#hm_1_0 > path'))))

g = parse_path(btm.get_attribute("d"))
u = []
for e in range (len(g)) :
    
    print(g[e])

driver.quit()```
that my output result :
``` Move(to=100j)
CubicBezier(start=100j, control1=(1+85.9j), control2=(2+32j), end=(5+29.5j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(5+29.5j), control1=(8+27j), control2=(11+75.6j), end=(15+87.5j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(15+87.5j), control1=(19+99.4j), control2=(21+88.6j), end=(25+89.1j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(25+89.1j), control1=(29+89.6j), control2=(31+90.3j), end=(35+90j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(35+90j), control1=(39+89.7j), control2=(41+88.5j), end=(45+87.6j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(45+87.6j), control1=(49+86.6j), control2=(51+86.4j), end=(55+85j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(55+85j), control1=(59+83.7j), control2=(61+81.3j), end=(65+80.9j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(65+80.9j), control1=(69+80.5j), control2=(71+84.8j), end=(75+83.2j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(75+83.2j), control1=(79+81.7j), control2=(81+73.9j), end=(85+73.3j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(85+73.3j), control1=(89+72.7j), control2=(91+78.5j), end=(95+80.1j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(95+80.1j), control1=(99+81.8j), control2=(101+80.3j), end=(105+81.6j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(105+81.6j), control1=(109+82.9j), control2=(111+85.2j), end=(115+86.9j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(115+86.9j), control1=(119+88.6j), control2=(121+89.4j), end=(125+90j), smooth=False)
CubicBezier(start=(125+90j), control1=(129+90.6j), control2=(131+90j), end=(135+90j), smooth=False)

CubicBezier(start=(625+83.9j), control1=(629+81j), control2=(631+75.7j), end=(635+75.3j), 
CubicBezier(start=(1000+65.4j), control1=(1001+72.3j), control2=(1000+93.1j), end=(1000+100j), smooth=False)```
````

Comment: Please read about [cubic Bézier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#b%C3%A9zier_curves). Also take a look at this: https://cubic-bezier.com/ The red ad the blue dots are the control points for the curve. The red one is control1. The blue one is the control2. The white dots are the start (bottom left) and the end (top right) points.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you are a great person to take time to respond to me.so the char j is what kind of factor?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using some SVG or graphing library that I'm not familiar with, and which you don't name.  Or possibly `CubicBezier()` is just a function in your code.  So there is not much we can tell you about that.

But I can tell you what the `j` is.  It is how [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) are represented in Python.  In normal mathematical notation, an `i` is used. The `i` represents the imaginary part of a comples number.  But Python uses a `j` instead. I don't know the history about why Python uses a `j`.

So, for example, with a number like `5+29.5j`. The `5` is the "real" part of the number, and `29.5` is the "imaginary" part of the number.

[This tutorial](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/imaginary-number-python/) does a decent job of introducing complex numbers in Python.

When complex numbers are graphed, normally the real part is used for the X coordinate, and the imaginary part is used as a Y coordinate.  So `5+29.5j` would be equivalent to `(x=5, y=29.5)`, or possibly `(x=5, y=-29.5)` - depending on what your code does.

Comment: ok, it didn't occur to me that there were complex numbers.
my code retrieves a graph in svg and tries to get the location of the largest curve and give me the x-coordinate of its middle (the largest y in some way). thank you for you response you are a  great peron